# Creating list of data frames for transcriptions in R using lapply or a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply, qdap

I'm trying to create a list of all my transcriptions that I would like to run text mining analyses on.

I'm using qdap to read in the transcriptions using the code below:

```
read.transcript(transcript1_filename,col.names = c("Person","Dialogue"),skip = 5)
```

This produces a data frame with two columns, one identifying the speaker and the other a strings of dialogue.

I have a lot of transcriptions so want to create a list to run further analyses on.

I've tried using lapply as so:

```
transcript_files = list.files("~/Transcripts",full.names = TRUE)
my_list = list()
my_list= lapply(transcript_files,read.transcript(),col.names = c("Person","Dialogue"),skip = 5)
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x) : argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

I have also tried a for loop as so:

```
for(i in length(transcript_files)){
my_list[[i]] = read.transcript(transcript_files[i],col.names = c("Person","Dialogue"),skip = 5)
}
```

But for some reason this only reads in the last file, all other entries in the list are NULL.

No idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: How does `transcript_files` look like?

Comment: Try with `read.transcript` (no parens) instead of `read.transcript()` in `lapply()`

Comment: @apom Awesome, removing the parentheses worked! Guess I was just too used to always adding those in automatically!

Comment: You need to enclose the file path in quotes in `list.files`

Comment: @JakeKaupp ah yes, no that was just a typo in the question here, it is correctly done in my code. Will edit the question.

Comment: @BigDataScientist transcript_files is a character vector of file paths for all of the .docx transcription files.